# max() functions with string argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the difference between below 2 max() functions with w in a small case and capitalized case? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max refers to the ASCII value of the characters . Capital letters has lower value than non capital letter .. therefore - r is the biggest value among the the second argument .